# How can I make a progress bar like this in React with Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, progress-bar

I want to make a progress bar in image with Material UI in React like this:

[image: image of progress bar]

I tried with a `customProgress` bar, something like:

```js
export const CustomLinearProgress = styled(LinearProgress)(({ theme }) => ({
  height: 35,
  borderRadius: 3,
   [`&.${ linearProgressClasses.colorPrimary }`]: {
     backgroundColor: '#00b4e559',
   },
   [`&.${ linearProgressClasses.bar }`]: {
     borderRadius: 3,
     backgroundColor: "#00B4E5"
   },
}));
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MUI's `CircularProgress` component and add a label for the progress percent inside it.

```
import * as React from "react";
import CircularProgress, {
  CircularProgressProps,
} from "@mui/material/CircularProgress";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

function CircularProgressWithLabel(
  props: CircularProgressProps & { value: number }
) {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ position: "relative", display: "inline-flex" }}>
      <CircularProgress
        variant="determinate"
        size={150}
        thickness={5}
        {...props}
      />
      <Box
        sx={{
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          right: 0,
          position: "absolute",
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Typography
          variant="caption"
          component="div"
          color="text.secondary"
        >{`${Math.round(props.value)}%`}</Typography>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default function CircularStatic() {
  const [progress, setProgress] = React.useState(10);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setProgress((prevProgress) =>
        prevProgress >= 100 ? 0 : prevProgress + 10
      );
    }, 800);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  return <CircularProgressWithLabel value={progress} />;
}
```

Change `size` and `thickness` props to achieve the style you want.
Learn more ways to control your circular progress in it's [API page](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/circular-progress/).